# django-rest-framework: not possible to update the simplest object with a serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to update an object with a Serializer, but **it just doesn't update anything at all**. I build the simplest app for testing and still no success.
I'm using **django 1.6.2** and **django-rest-framework 2.3.13**

My `models.py` (Note: the `blank` and `noblank` field names are misleading, I know. It's just that I wanted to try before wether the problem was caused by blank fields, but it is not):

```
from django.db import 

class Test(models.Model):
    blank = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    noblank = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{0} - {1}".format(self.blank, self.noblank)
```

My `serializers.py`:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from update_test.models import Test

class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Test
```

And the tests I did in the shell:

```
In [1]: from update_test.models import *

In [2]: from update_test.serializers import *

In [3]: 

In [3]: 

In [3]: test1 = Test.objects.first()

In [4]: 

In [4]: serializer1 = TestSerializer(test1)

In [5]: serializer1.data
Out[5]: {u'id': 1, 'blank': u'blank1', 'noblank': u'noblank1'}

In [6]: 

In [6]: from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer

In [7]: 

In [7]: json1 = JSONRenderer().render(serializer1.data)

In [8]: json1
Out[8]: '{"id": 1, "blank": "blank1", "noblank": "noblank1"}'

In [9]: 

In [9]: from StringIO import StringIO

In [10]: from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser

In [11]: 

In [11]: stream1 = StringIO(json1)

In [12]: data1 = JSONParser().parse(stream1)

In [13]: 

In [13]: serializer1 = TestSerializer(data=data1)

In [14]: serializer1.is_valid()
Out[14]: True

In [15]: 

In [15]: serializer1.object
Out[15]: <Test: blank1 - noblank1>

In [16]: 

In [16]: data1[u'blank'] = u'test'

In [17]: data1[u'noblank'] = u'notest'

In [18]: 

In [18]: deser = TestSerializer(test1, data=data1)

In [19]: 

In [19]: deser.data
Out[19]: {u'id': 1, 'blank': u'blank1', 'noblank': u'noblank1'}

In [20]: deser.save()
Out[20]: <Test: blank1 - noblank1>

In [21]: deser.object
Out[21]: <Test: blank1 - noblank1>
```

As you can see from line 18, I passed the object to update and the new data to the serializer. But neither the object nor the serializer didn't change at all.

This is the simplest example and it's quite the same as the one in the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers.html#deserializing-objects). 
Does someone see if I forgot something?

Comment: Hi Esparver, I cannot replicate the issue using the same steps. However, I wonder if that last serializer you create is invalid. Between steps 18 & 19 what does `deser.is_valid()` and `deser.errors` show?

Comment: @Fiver yes I forgot to copy that part, but `deser.is_valid()` returns `True` and `deser.errors()` is empty. I'm thinking it might be a bug, could you please tell me which version of the rest-framework are you using?

Comment: Sure, I'm using the same 2.3.13

Comment: the save() method should return the saved object instance which is just returning the serializer's instance attribute. Have you tried looking at that property first?